# SKReceiptRefreshRequest delegate causing rejection; can't find usage in my code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, receipt

### Short Version

Apple rejected my app, saying I am using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`, but I can't find it in my code(below).

### Long Version

I am currently in the process of trying to get my app approved on the app store and running into a few walls. The main issue currently is that they are saying I have implemented receipt validation incorrectly, When based on their documents I have done as they have specified, to my knowledge. They then directed me to a Developer Technical Support representative. He then proceeds to go through the process of elimination -- based on speculation, which stems from not being able to see my code and not having any contact with the app review department.

Firstly he mentions `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and a grand unifying receipt. I informed him I am not using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`; I searched through the whole project. We then went through some more elimination and eventually I ended up sending an .IPA along with provisioning profiles for the DTS representative to personally test. He reported back he saw no issues and would contact the app review department to find the reason for the rejection. Finally some progress.

And he comes back saying

> "*The issue here is that App Review is rejecting your app for the use
>   of the SKReceiptRefreshRequest. The App Reviewer is using some sequence
>   of steps which results in the app making this call. The app just needs
>   to not reuqire this method to complete in order for the reviewer to
>   access the in app purchase items - the Buy button.*"

...

So my only conclusion is that I am somehow using a delegate of this method in my code somewhere. Can anyone tell me where I am, or might be, using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`, 'cause i am stumped (code below).

## More info

### code

**(partially obscured for security)**

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import "SKProduct+LocalizedPrice.h"
#import ***
#import "NSString+NSStringAdditions.h"
#import ***
#import ***
#import ***
#import ***

@implementation IAPHelper
@synthesize productIdentifiers = _productIdentifiers;
@synthesize products = _products;
@synthesize purchasedProducts = _purchasedProducts;
@synthesize request = _request;
@synthesize localProducts = _localProducts;
@synthesize productsCategory = _productsCategory;


- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        NSMutableSet * purchasedProducts = [NSMutableSet set];
        _localProducts = [NSMutableArray new];


        [_localProducts addObjectsFromArray:***];
        [_localProducts addObjectsFromArray:***];
        [_localProducts addObjectsFromArray:***];

        _productsCategory = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        [_productsCategory setObject:[self sortAndTrimProducts:***] forKey:***];
        [_productsCategory setObject:[self sortAndTrimProducts:***] forKey:***];
        [_productsCategory setObject:[self sortAndTrimProducts:***] forKey:***];

        self.purchasedProducts = purchasedProducts;

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)getProducts:(NSMutableArray*)array forId:(int)Id
{
    for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers)
    {
        NSArray *stringByComponent = [productIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
        int identifier = [[stringByComponent objectAtIndex:*] integerValue];

        BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];


        if (productPurchased)
        {
            [_purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];
            DDLogInfo(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }
        else
        {
            DDLogInfo(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
        }

        if (identifier == Id)
        {
            [array addObject:productIdentifier];
        }

    }
}

-(NSMutableArray*)sortAndTrimProducts:(NSMutableArray*)array
{

    NSArray *sortedProducts = [self sortProducts:array];

    NSMutableArray *returnedArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSString *string in sortedProducts)
    {
        NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];

        int type = [[components objectAtIndex:*] integerValue];

        switch (type)
        {
            case ***:
            {
                NSString *productName = [components objectAtIndex:*];

                [returnedArray addObject:productName];
            }
                break;

            case ***:
            {
                NSString *productName = [components objectAtIndex:*];

                [returnedArray addObject:productName];
            }
                break;

            case ***:
            {
                NSString *productName = [components objectAtIndex:*];

                [returnedArray addObject:productName];
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return returnedArray;
}

- (NSArray*)sortProducts:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b)
                   {
                      ***
                   }];

    return sortedArray;
}

- (void)requestProducts
{
    self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _request.delegate = self;
    [_request start];
}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    // 1
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    // 2
    _request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _request.delegate = self;
    [_request start];

}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{    
    DDLogInfo(@"Received products results...%@",response.products);
    self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;

    for( int i = 0; i < [_products count]; ++i )
    {
        if ( [_products objectAtIndex:i] )
        {
            DDLogInfo(@"Product title: %@" , [[_products objectAtIndex:i] localizedTitle]);
            DDLogInfo(@"Product description: %@" , [[_products objectAtIndex:i] localizedDescription]);
            DDLogInfo(@"Product price: %@" , [[_products objectAtIndex:i] localizedPrice]);
            DDLogInfo(@"Product id: %@" , [[_products objectAtIndex:i] productIdentifier]);
        }

        for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        {
            DDLogError(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:_products];
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DDLogError(@"Failed to load list of products. %@",error.localizedDescription);
    _request = nil;
}

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{

}

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSArray *formattedarrayFromString = [productIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
    NSString *type = [formattedarrayFromString objectAtIndex:*];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                                 @"data"    :   formattedarrayFromString,
                                 @"ID"      :   productIdentifier,
                                 };

    if ( type.integerValue == 1 )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:*** object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
    }
    else
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"Toggling flag for: %@", productIdentifier);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:productIdentifier];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [_purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier];
    }
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    DDLogInfo(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    DDLogInfo(@"%@",response);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    DDLogInfo(@"Succeeded! Received bytes of data");    // Deal with an error
}
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    DDLogInfo(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction 
{

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        DDLogError(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object:transaction];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    DDLogInfo(@"%@",productIdentifier);
    DDLogInfo(@"%@",_purchasedProducts);
    return [_purchasedProducts containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{
    DDLogInfo(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

+ (NSString*) encode:(const uint8_t*) input length:(NSInteger) length
{
    ***
}

- (void)validateReceiptForTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    MyVerificationController * verifier = [MyVerificationController sharedInstance];

    [verifier verifyPurchaseForProduction:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
    {
        if(success)
        {
            DDLogInfo(@"successfully verified receipt!");
            [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
        }
        else
        {
            if (error.code == 21007)
            {
                [verifier verifyPurchaseForSandbox:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
                {
                    if(success)
                    {
                        DDLogInfo(@"successfully verified receipt!");
                        [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DDLogError(@"Failed to validate receipt.");
                        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:*** object:nil userInfo:nil];
                    }
                }];
            }
            else
            {
                DDLogError(@"Failed to validate receipt.");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:*** object:nil userInfo:nil];
            }
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

We only host consumables on apples server for them to purchase, all non-consumables which is supposedly causing the issue are handled directly by us and is tied to their account on our server.

Delegates I am using in the class above

`<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver,NSURLConnectionDelegate>`

Comment: Please include minimal relevant code in your question body here, rather than a link. Questions on SO need to be self-contained so that they remain useful in the future.

Comment: I understand it's a bit long and some if not all is irrelevant, but the problem has gotten to the point where I don't know what is or is not relevant in the context of where -according to apple- I am using SKReceiptRefreshRequest so better to post it all yet I also do not want to make the post a mess with a whole class posted in it for reference. In the interest of helping others though, once this is resolved (hopefully) I will edit my post with the explicit code that was the issue.EDIT:Just noticed you deleted the links already...should I just post the whole class then per your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, please put the code into the post.